# diference between return , echo and print keyword in PHP

Tags: php

What is the difference between these three?

return , echo and print keyword in PHP

```
function theBand($abc,$bac) {

return $abc;
echo $abc;

}
```

Both does the same, it does show or return me the value holding in the variable abc. Now return exists the function and echo continues. Apart from this is there anything specific on return keyword.

Comment: Both don't do the same work though, you're wrong.

Comment: `echo` & `print` prints to screen literally. `Return` just gives you the value to THEN do what you want to it, ie. `echo`. `Return` is better in many cases.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) is a language construct used to exit a function and give a value to the caller of the function.

[`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) and [`print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) are both language constructs that output strings. The main difference is that echo can take multiple arguments separated by commas, but print accepts only a single argument.

Comment: what does this statement of yours mean?

give a value to the caller of the function and does echo and print does not exit a function from performing the next statement

Comment: @theband: I'm not sure exactly what you need me to clarify. `return` is pretty much the same in PHP as it is in any other language - it returns a value. Have you used `return` before in any language? Is there a specific word in my answer that you don't understand? Do you know about functions and their purpose? Regarding your second question, you are right that `print` and `echo` do not cause the function to exit. Execution continues on the next line.

Comment: I have updated my question, please do check and thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

`return` is used when a function has to return a value.

please see [HERE](http://www.faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/1/fid/40)

`echo` and `print` are very similar however `echo` is faster as it does not return a value.

1. Speed.  There is a difference between the two, but speed-wise it should be irrelevant which one you use.  `echo` is marginally faster since it doesn't set a return value if you really want to get down to the nitty gritty.
2. Expression.  `print()` behaves like a function in that you can do:

   ```
   $ret = print "Hello World";
   ```

   And `$ret` will be 1.  That means that `print` can be used as part of a more complex expression where `echo` cannot.  An example from the PHP Manual:

   ```
   $b ? print "true" : print "false";
   ```

   `print` is also part of the precedence table which it needs to be if it is
   to be used within a complex expression. It is just about at the bottom
   of the precedence list though.  Only "`,`", `AND`, `OR` and `XOR` are lower.
3. Parameter(s).  The grammar is: `echo expression [, expression[, expression] ... ]`. But `echo ( expression, expression )` is not valid. This would be valid: `echo ("howdy"),("partner");` the same as: `echo "howdy","partner";` (Putting the brackets in that simple example serves no purpose since there is no operator precedence issue with a single
   term like that.)

So, `echo` without parentheses can take multiple parameters, which get
concatenated:

```
echo  "and a ", 1, 2, 3;   // comma-separated without parentheses
echo ("and a 123");        // just one parameter with parentheses
```

`print()` can only take one parameter:

```
print ("and a 123");
print  "and a 123";
```

Comment: I thought some proper formatting would look nice on your answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

print returns 1, while echo returns nothing.  Echo also can take multiple arguments, as Mark points out.

return (in the context of a function) exits the function (Returning a value, if provided).  In the global context, return will stop executing whatever file it's in.  So you can bail out of an include file, or halt execution of the main script this way.