# how to write url in ajax request in codeigniter php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

i'm new to codeigniter i can't not get data from the controller using the ajax request i think i do mistake in writing the url of the controller function in ajax call

**here is the code of my ajax call**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fname").focusout(function(){
       // alert();
              $.ajax({
                  url: "<?php echo base_url();?>/proposal/ajax_load",
                  type: 'POST',
                  success: function(result){
                        $("#div1").html(result);
                    }
        });  
    });
});
```

**Here is my controller**

```
class Proposal extends CI_Controller {
 public function ajax_load()
  {
        return ("Hello");
    }

 }
```

Comment: can you write my url in proper way so that i can copy it into my code

Comment: its not working i tried

Comment: it should be like this ` url: "http://localhost/CodeIgnitorTutorial/index.php/usercontroller/verifyUser",`

Comment: Check in network tab which url it is taking.

Comment: seems like you missed name of page in url , it should be like url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "page.php/ajax_post_controller/user_data_submit"

Comment: http://localhost/proposal/proposal/new_user
it is the url

Comment: @shani : it should be http://localhost//**proposal.php**/proposal/new_user or pagename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confuse between the meaning of `[Return, Echo]` in PHP,

#### [Echo](http://php.net/echo)

> echo — Output one or more strings

#### [Return](http://php.net/return)

> return returns program control to the calling module. Execution
>   resumes at the expression following the called module's invocation.

and as long as the Ajax response callback is reading a server response [output], you must send an output to the server.

```
public function ajax_load()
{
    echo "Hello";
}
```

Further reading :-

- [What is the difference between PHP echo and PHP return in plain English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387765/what-is-the-difference-between-php-echo-and-php-return-in-plain-english)
- [Difference between php echo and return in terms of a jQuery ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107144/difference-between-php-echo-and-return-in-terms-of-a-jquery-ajax-call)
- a short and simple [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2710117/2359679)

Answer (score 1):

in **ajax_load()** - Should be **echo** not **return** if you're getting a response via ajax.