# how to concatinate base_url and string in echo php

Tags: php, codeigniter

i cannot print my desire path in the form action i set a condition that id the **$edit** array is set then page goes to **add_new_proposal** function which i define in my controller and if the **$edit** variable is not set then it goes to **edit_new_proposal** function

**here is the code of action of form**

```
 <form role="form" method="post" action="<?php if(isset($edit)){echo 'base_url();proposal/add_new_proposal';}else{echo 'base_url();proposal/edit_new_proposal';}?> " enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: `echo base_url() . 'proposal/add_new_proposal';` read more about [concatenation in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: can you give ma a feed back on my this Question i will be very thankful to you
Here is the 
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49337923/how-to-write-url-in-ajax-request-in-codeigniter-php?noredirect=1#comment85677023_49337923)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
echo 'base_url();proposal/add_new_proposal';
```

to:

```
echo base_url().'proposal/add_new_proposal';
```

And

```
echo 'base_url();proposal/edit_new_proposal';
```

to:

```
echo base_url().'proposal/edit_new_proposal';
```

Comment: Combining strings together: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336858/how-to-combine-two-strings-together-in-php

Comment: thanks so much for your feed back

Comment: can you give ma a feed back on my this Question i will be very thankful to you
Here is the 
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49337923/how-to-write-url-in-ajax-request-in-codeigniter-php?noredirect=1#comment85677023_49337923)

Answer (score -1):

According to your code base_url() is a function and you are adding it as a string in the echo statement. Change it as shown below:

```
 <form role="form" method="post" action="<?php if(isset($edit)){echo base_url() . ‘proposal/add_new_proposal';}else{echo base_url() . ‘proposal/edit_new_proposal';}?> " enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: thanku very much  :)

Comment: hungersoft can you give ma a feed back on my this Question i will be very thankful to you
Here is the 
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49337923/how-to-write-url-in-ajax-request-in-codeigniter-php?noredirect=1#comment85677023_49337923)